# Detect scroll down user action repeat many times and redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, html

When I detect the user are trying to scroll down many times, I want to redirect him to another page, can someone help me? I don't know exactly how to do that

Comment: You forgot to post the code that attempts to solve this problem.

Comment: what means "many times"?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.